# SQL Error Code: 1452 when inserting data into table with FK referring to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database

I am currently trying to populate my tables with data via a SQL script and have been having issues getting my `FKs` cooperate while populating my `book` table. I've read the other threads on the issue and have tried `ON DELETE CASCADE` and the other suggestions of populating the FKs first didn't work for me either. I also saw you can override the `FK` check however that seems counterproductive to making a working database.

I've attached my scripts and `create.sql` runs fine but `insert.sql` as I said gets stuck on the last command.

Thanks for your time!

```
-----
create.sql
-----
CREATE TABLE Dept (
    Dept_ID INT(2) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Name CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Floor INT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Dept_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Publisher (
    Publisher_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PubAddress VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone_Number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Publisher_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
    Book_ID INT(6) NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
    Dept_ID INT(2),
    Publisher_Name VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (Book_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Dept_ID) REFERENCES Dept(Dept_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Publisher_Name) REFERENCES Publisher(Publisher_Name)
);
-----
insert.sql
-----
INSERT INTO Dept (Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Dept_Floor) 
VALUES ('01', 'Fantasy', '1'), ('02', 'Sci-Fi', '1'), ('03', 'Fiction', '2'), ('04', 'Educational', '1'), ('05', 'Crime', '2');

INSERT INTO Publisher (Publisher_Name, PubAddress, Phone_Number)
VALUES ('Bloomsbury', '234 Hay Street', '14325673489'), ('Charles Scribner','236 Hone Way','173677654765'),('Pigeon Books','5444 North Street','17884787644'), ('Academic Press', '2354 Bridge Road', '175634598234'), ('Bantam Books', '2623 River Road', '17234648444');

INSERT INTO Book (Book_ID, Title, Dept_ID, Publisher_Name) 
VALUES ('000001','Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire', '01', 'Bloomsbury'), ('000002','A Brief History of Time', '04', 'Puffin Books'), ('000003','The Great Gatsby', 'Charles Scribners Sons', '03'), ('000004','Advances in Ecological Research', 'Academic Press', '04'), ('000005','The Case of Joe', 'Bantam Books', '05');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `columns` are not aligned and your `data length` is too small for your given data.

```
CREATE TABLE Dept (
    Dept_ID INT(2) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Name CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    Dept_Floor INT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Dept_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Publisher (
    Publisher_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PubAddress VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Phone_Number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Publisher_Name)
);

CREATE TABLE Book (
    Book_ID INT(6) NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    Dept_ID INT(2),
    Publisher_Name VARCHAR(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (Book_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Dept_ID) REFERENCES Dept(Dept_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Publisher_Name) REFERENCES Publisher(Publisher_Name)
);

INSERT INTO Dept (Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Dept_Floor) 
VALUES ('01', 'Fantasy', '1'), ('02', 'Sci-Fi', '1'), ('03', 'Fiction', '2'), ('04', 'Educational', '1'), ('05', 'Crime', '2');

INSERT INTO Publisher (Publisher_Name, PubAddress, Phone_Number)
VALUES ('Bloomsbury', '234 Hay Street', '14325673489'), ('Charles Scribner','236 Hone Way','173677654765'),('Pigeon Books','5444 North Street','17884787644'), ('Academic Press', '2354 Bridge Road', '175634598234'), ('Bantam Books', '2623 River Road', '17234648444');

INSERT INTO Book (Book_ID, Title, Dept_ID, Publisher_Name) 
VALUES ('000001','Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire', '01', 'Bloomsbury'), ('000002','A Brief History of Time', '04', 'Bantam Books'), ('000003','The Great Gatsby', '03', 'Charles Scribner'), ('000004','Advances in Ecological Research', '04', 'Academic Press'), ('000005','The Case of Joe',  '05', 'Bantam Books');
```

Comment: Woof, pretty brutal mistakes. Thank you, this fixed my issues.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this error/failure means that the foreign key constraint is working correctly. The book insert is failing because you're trying to insert a book with a publisher that doesn't exist. Two of them, in fact:

('000003','The Great Gatsby', 'Charles Scribners Sons', '03')

You don't have "Charles Scribners Sons" publisher, only "Charles Scribner".

('000002','A Brief History of Time', '04', 'Puffin Books'),

You don't have Puffin Books publisher, only Pigeon Books.

Also, your book records are wrong, the last two of them. They've got Publisher name, then Dept ID...

In short, this is precisely the case when precisely this error should occur, because your data is malformed.

Comment: Ah whoops. I changed some data before posting here since it's from a bigger DB and wanted it to make sense in this context. But the issue in my real DB was the ID alignment, so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Create.sql` and `insert.sql` both having data size and ordering issue.
I just corrected your query and now it will work fine for you.

```
---create.sql----
CREATE TABLE Dept (
    Dept_ID INT NOT NULL
    ,Dept_Name CHAR(16) NOT NULL
    ,Dept_Floor INT NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Dept_ID)
    );

CREATE TABLE Publisher (
    Publisher_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,PubAddress VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
    ,Phone_Number VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Publisher_Name)
    );

CREATE TABLE Book (
    Book_ID INT NOT NULL
    ,Title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ,Dept_ID INT
    ,Publisher_Name VARCHAR(50)
    ,PRIMARY KEY (Book_ID)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (Dept_ID) REFERENCES Dept(Dept_ID)
    ,FOREIGN KEY (Publisher_Name) REFERENCES Publisher(Publisher_Name)
    );


---insert.sql---
INSERT INTO Dept (Dept_ID, Dept_Name, Dept_Floor) 
VALUES ('01', 'Fantasy', '1'), ('02', 'Sci-Fi', '1'), ('03', 'Fiction', '2'), ('04', 'Educational', '1'), ('05', 'Crime', '2');

INSERT INTO Publisher (Publisher_Name, PubAddress, Phone_Number)
VALUES ('Bloomsbury', '234 Hay Street', '14325673489'), ('Charles Scribner','236 Hone Way','173677654765'),('Pigeon Books','5444 North Street','17884787644'), ('Academic Press', '2354 Bridge Road', '175634598234'), ('Bantam Books', '2623 River Road', '17234648444');

INSERT INTO Book (Book_ID, Title, Dept_ID, Publisher_Name) 
VALUES ('000001','Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire', '01', 'Bloomsbury'), ('000002','A Brief History of Time', '04', 'Charles Scribner'), ('000003','The Great Gatsby', '03','Pigeon Books'), ('000004','Advances in Ecological Research', '04','Academic Press'), ('000005','The Case of Joe', '05','Bantam Books' );
```